# how to get sum of column based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_RT_GetProdutstogrid]
@branch int

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   select PS.sno, PD.productname,sum(PS.quantity) as quantity,PS.description from 
   K_RT_PurchaseDet PS 
   inner join K_RT_ProductDetails PD on PD.sno=PS.product where purchasedby=@branch 
   and PS.company=@company and modelno=@modelno 
   group by PS.quantity,PS.sno, PD.productname,PS.description
END
```

how to sum quantity when company and modelno are same

Comment: i mean there are 2 rows with same company and modelno the how to sum quantity

Comment: Where is your company and modelno in your input parameters?? From where these coming?

Answer (score 1):

Try This , No need to include quantity in GROUP BY

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_RT_GetProdutstogrid]
@branch int

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   select PS.sno, PD.productname,sum(PS.quantity) as quantity,PS.description from 
   K_RT_PurchaseDet PS 
   inner join K_RT_ProductDetails PD on PD.sno=PS.product where purchasedby=@branch 
   and PS.company=@company and modelno=@modelno and PS.company=modelno
   group by PS.sno, PD.productname,PS.description
END
```

Comment: i want to get sum of quantity when there are many rows with same company and modelno

Comment: i am getting like this     mobile      3      1     1                          mobile      3     1